# Track Changes in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet I need to edit and would like to be able to make all my edits in red so I know what has been modified.

Is there a way I can do this without having to format each cell as I go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are instructions on how to turn on **Change Tracking**
To turn on change tracking, follow these steps:

1. Select **Review**➝ **Track Changes**➝ **Highlight Changes**.
   The Highlight Changes dialog box appears.
2. Turn on the **Track changes while editing** checkbox.
   When you turn on change tracking, you also automatically switch on workbook sharing a separate feature. There’s no way to turn on change tracking without also turning on workbook sharing.
3. Ignore the Who, When, and Where checkboxes for now, and click OK to return to your worksheet.

More information can be found on [GeekDeck](http://geekdeck.com/excel-2010-tracking-changes-made-to-a-worksheet/).